# Converting Java code to model view controller architecture pattern

Tags: java, view, model, controller, software-design

I have written some code in java to give the some of the numbers 1 to 10 and then also display the average. I would like to change this to the model view controller method(thats what the tutor wants). We only had one lesson on it and i dont really understand how do change it. If someone could go through this and show me how(as if they were trying to teach a 5 year old) that would be great.

```
//JAVA CODE
public class Ex4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        int average = 0;
        for (int i=1; i < 10; i++){

            sum = sum + i;
            average = sum/i;

        }
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
        System.out.println("The average is " + average);

    }    
}
```

Comment: You do realize that average of integers might not be an integer, right?

Answer (score 5):

MVC is a basic pattern where you separate the model (data), view (display), and controller (logic) into different files and directories.

Here is an illustration of this model:

[image]

Here is an example of how that might look with your current code:

Controller Class (with main method included):

```
public class Ex4Controller {
    //You could create a second controller, 
    //and put the main method there, 
    //then create a controller object. 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //Initialize model
        Ex4Model number = new Ex4Model(0,0.0);

        //Execute business logic 
        Ex4Controller.getSumAndAverage(number); 

        //Set view
        Ex4View.printSum(number.sum, number.average);
    }
    
    //Logic method
    private static void getSumAndAverage(Ex4Model numbers){
        
        for (int i=1; i < 10; i++){
            //Here the controller interfaces with 
            //the model
            numbers.sum = numbers.sum + i;
            numbers.average = numbers.sum/i;

        }
    }

}
```

The controller class interfaces with both the `model` and the `view`. This class is where you do all the processes, and update the model or view. Any logic done, is going to be done in this class. If you wanted to get the mean of the numbers, you would write a method called `getmean()` in this class. Data manipulation is ONLY done here.

This is the Model class:

```
public class Ex4Model {

    public int sum = 0;
    public double average = 0;
    
    //Custom constructor to set values
    public Ex4Model(int sum, double average){
        this.sum = sum;
        this.average = average; 
    }

}
```

This class is used to hold the data. No logic is done here. This is a basic data structure that you use to house the data. This class does not interface with the view.

This is your view class:

```
public class Ex4View {

    public static void printSum(int sum, double average){
         System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
           System.out.println("The average is " + average);
    }
}
```

This isn't a true view, but it's the best demonstration considering the circumstances. With Java, you would put your swing files here. The job of these files is to display the data. You'll notice that the controller passes all the data to this class, rather than accessing the data from the model.

This will output to the console:

> The sum is 45
>
> The average is 5.0

Something to keep in mind with MVC, is that you can have multiple controllers, models, and views. This is a very simple example. By using MVC, developers & programmers are able to better organize the data. They know where everything is being done, rather than having views manipulate data in some area's, and not in others.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As a (very) rough guideline:

Model: Stores the data.  In this case, the sum and the average.

View: Displays the data.  In this case, writing the data out with `System.out`.  When the model changes, update the display (write the new values out).

Controller:  Manipulates the data.  In this case, taking an array of ints, computing sum and average, and giving the results to the model.

So overall, Controller computes sum & average, gives those values to Model.  View is notified that Model changed.  View displays Model's values.

Comment: I understand this but how do i write it?

Comment: To start, create three classes.  A model, a view, and a controller.  Then take the code in `Ex4` and determine which class each line should go in.

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 classes:

Let say `Ex4Model`, which just has 2 member variables in it called `sum` and `average`, and the corresponding `get` and `set` methods for each. This will hold your data.

We can then create the view, lets say `Ex4View`, which has a method say called `render(Ex4Model model)` which outputs the stuff you want from the model, in your case the `sum` and `average`.

Then you can create the controller, `Ex4Controller`, which has a method `calculate()`. Inside it it performs the calculations and feeds them to the model (in this simple example you can just create a new instance of it) and then calls `render()` on the view.

The rest is for you to join together, this is your homework.